# Как вызвать функцию класса внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

Не вижу в чем проблема, может туплю. Перепроверил уже несколько раз

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class tri_d:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.a_value = -3
        self.b_value = 3
        self.symbol_x = sp.Symbol("x")
        self.symbol_y = sp.Symbol("y")

    def get_vector(self, a, b):
        return np.arange(a, b + 1, 0.1)

    def plot_2d_function(self, function, a, b):
        # Create the sympy function f(x)
        f_x = sp.sympify(function)

        # Create domain and image
        domain_x = get_vector(a, b)
        image = [f_x.subs(self.symbol_x, value) for value in domain_x]

        # Plot the 2D function graph
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        plt.plot(domain_x, image)
        plt.show()

    def plot_3d_function(self, function, a, b):
        # Create sympy function f(x, y)
        f_xy = sp.lambdify((self.symbol_x, self.symbol_y), sp.sympify(function))

        # Create domains and image
        domain_x = get_vector(a, b)
        domain_y = get_vector(a, b)
        domain_x, domain_y = np.meshgrid(domain_x, domain_y)
        image = f_xy(domain_x, domain_y)

        # Plot the 3D function graph
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
        ax.plot_surface(domain_x, domain_y, image, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap="viridis")
        plt.show()

    def main(self):
        plot_2d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
        plot_3d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)

app = tri_d("x**2 + y**2")
app.main()
```

ошибка:

```
line 48, in main
plot_2d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
NameError: name 'plot_2d_function' is not defined
```

Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Удалите скрин, добавьте код.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо за указание на ошибку

Comment: Для вызова внутренних методов, необходимо писать так: `self.plot_2d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)`

Comment: Сработала только без первого self в аргументе: self.plot_2d_function(self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)

Comment: Хороший ответ Вам уже дали. От себя рискну добавить, что не вижу смысла передавать методы в качестве аргументов функции вместо того, чтобы использовать их внутри самой функции являющейся `classmethod`. Единственное когда может быть целесообразно такое использование если вызываемые функции могу принимать другие значения, отличные от значений методов класса

Answer (score 3):

*Предсловие:*

Методы, определенные в вашем классе, назначены для вызова из *объектов* этого класса (в виде `объект.метод(параметры)`.

Первым параметром в определении этих методов является *ссылка на самой объект этого класса,* обыкновенно (но не обязательно) имея имя `self`.

Почему? Потому, что для разных объектов метод может делать разные вещи, а так метод должен знать, на какой объект он применяется: запись типа

```
объект.метод(параметры)
```

передает методу как первый параметр ссылку на сам объект:

```
метод(объект, параметры)
```

---

Теперь, почему ошибка в определении вашего метода `main()`, т.е. в вашем коде

```
def main(self):
    plot_2d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
    plot_3d_function(self, self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
```

?

Потому, что самостоятельные функции `plot_2d_function()` и `plot_3d_function()` **не существуют**, т.к. они **не** определены **вне** вашего класса.

Но ваш метод `main()` принимает в параметре `self` ссылку на объект, который его вызывал, и вы хотите *для того же самого объекта*  вызвать ваши методы `plot_2d_function()` и `plot_3d_function()`, т.е сделать это:

```
def main(self):
    self.plot_2d_function(self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
    self.plot_3d_function(self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
```

Такие вызовы методов передают вашим методам `plot_2d_function()` и `plot_3d_function()` **автоматически** как первый параметр ссылку на объект (т.е. `self`), потому он как параметр при вызове методов уже не задавается.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы получить доступ к методам класса внутри класса, в каждый метод передается переменная self, которая содержит ссылки на все методы класса.

Для доступа к методам из класса, необходимо их вызывать через self

```
def main(self):
    self.plot_2d_function(self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
    self.plot_3d_function(self.function, self.a_value, self.b_value)
```

Так же, обратите внимание, что в явном виде, передача self не нужна.